# Parse Issue in Xcode 4.6.3 - "Expected a type" - Can't find the error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Problem with Xcode:

At the moment I am working on an application for iOS SDK 6.1. Somedays ago I was implementing some methods and tried to compile the project.
Then something strange happened:

Compilation failed and I got some errors (see picture below) in two files, which aren't related to the methods I worked on.

[image]

I searched for errors in my code but couldn't find any.
Then I closed the project and opened it again: They were still here.
Then I closed the project and Xcode and reopened both: They were still here.
Then I created a new project and copied all the code: The issue appeared again.

Now I am stuck and have no clue what to do. Do I miss something in my code?

**Please help me!**

### ---

EDIT 1:

Here are some code snippets, which should show my code after I followed the suggestions of Martin R:

```
//  PlayingCardDeck.h  
@class PlayingCard;  
@interface PlayingCardDeck : NSObject  
- (void) addCard: (PlayingCard *) card atTop: (BOOL) atTop;  
- (PlayingCard *) drawRandomCard;  
- (BOOL) containsCard: (PlayingCard *) card;  
- (BOOL) isCardUsed: (PlayingCard *) card;  
- (void) drawSpecificCard: (PlayingCard *) card;  
- (void) reset;  
@end
```

---

```
//  PlayingCardDeck.m  
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"  
@interface PlayingCardDeck()
```

---

```
//  PlayingCard.h  
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
#import "RobinsConstants.h"  
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"  
//@class PlayingCardDeck;  
@interface PlayingCard :  NSObject  
+ (NSArray*) suitStrings;  
+ (NSArray*) rankStrings;  
+ (NSUInteger) maxRank;  
- (id)initCardWithRank: (NSUInteger) r andSuit: (NSString*) s;  
- (NSString*) description;  
- (NSUInteger) pokerEvalRankWithDeck: (PlayingCardDeck *) deck;  
- (NSAttributedString *) attributedContents;  
- (BOOL) isEqual:(PlayingCard*)object;  
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;  
@property (nonatomic, getter = isUsed) BOOL used;  
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger rank;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString * suit;  
@end
```

---

```
//  PlayingCard.m  
#import "PlayingCard.h"  
@interface  PlayingCard()
```

---

Comment: do you have zoombie objects enabled??? if not then enable it edit scheme>>Diagnostic  this will probably tell you the reason..

Comment: I don't see a picture of the error...I'm not sure whether that's your problem or mine.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to link the picture...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That looks like a typical "import cycle":

```
 // In PlayingCardDeck.h:
 @import "PlayingCard.h"

 // In PlayingCard.h:
 @import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
```

Replacing one of the `@import` statements by `@class` should solve the problem, e.g.

```
 // In PlayingCardDeck.h:
 @class PlayingCard; // instead of @import "PlayingCard.h"
```

And in the implementation file you have to import the full interface:

```
 // In PlayingCardDeck.m:
 #import "PlayingCardDeck.h"  
 #import "PlayingCard.h"    // <-- add this one
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But now I have a whole bunch of new errors:

Comment: @RobindeBois: It is difficult to help without more information.

Comment: Yes.. I am sorry, something went wrong...
[Link to the picture](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3373/uebkas9g_png.htm)

Comment: @RobindeBois put the `@class PlayingCard;` at the top of your `PlayingCardDeck.h` file...

Comment: @RobindeBois: I cannot guess the error from that screenshot. It would be much more helpful if you add the (relevant) code and the error messages as *text* to your question.

Comment: I really don't know which part of the code is relevant, because I don't know where the problem comes from...  
All the errors appear to be in the `PlayingCardDeck.m` file. So I copy all the code of `PlayingCard` and of `PlayingCardDeck` to the original question... okay?

Comment: @RobindeBois: The complete .h files and all import statements of the .m files might be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR: I added the code snippets that you suggested to the original question.. If you need more, just say it.. and thanks to everyone for the efforts.. Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in PlayingCard.h. This error causes the compiler to not know what a "PlayingCard *" is.
Can you show the code from PlayingCard.h?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PlayingCard.m is added to your applications target! I would think it isn't (click the .m file and check your apps target in the inspector window on the right side pane)